# Disable auto generated email on Google Drive file sharing

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using Google Drive API to upload files from our custom application. When I use the Google Drive API permissions to share a uploaded file with an individual user, an auto generated email is always sent to the user indicating that a new file has been shared.

Is there any option in Google Drive API to disable this auto generated email? I can see the option in Drive UI, but cannot see the same option while using the Drive API.

In case auto generated mail cannot be disabled, is there a way to customize the auto generated email contents?

Thank you,
CD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can both disable the email message entirely or set a custom message for the email. See the [permissions insert function](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert), you'll want to look at the sendNotificationEmails and emailMessage attributes. These are URI parameters, not body parameters so you would set them in the same way you set the fileId. For example, the Python example would look like:

```
return service.permissions().insert(
    fileId=file_id, sendNotificationEmails=False, body=new_permission).execute()
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Works as advised.

Comment: This works even after the limit is flagged to have been reached.